# When using # to find array length, the array is Null

Tags: lua

So I have an array of people that I want to choose from at random...

```
local strong = {

'Laura',
'David',
'Christopher'

}
```

How would I pick randomly from this table? So far I have ran

```
print(math.random(#strong))
```

But when I run that get this error

```
lua: again.lua:19: attempt to get length of global 'strong' (a nil value)
```

Why would the array be nil, even though there is something inside the array?

Comment: [Can not reproduce](http://ideone.com/5MPzwW).  Show the exact code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Lua interactively, put everything inside a `do` block, or remove `local` from your table variable to make it global.  The interpreter executes each statement separately, losing the `local` of the previous statement.

Also, set the random seed with something like: `math.randomseed(os.time())` to avoid getting the same value each run.